# Filtering with Goutte in Symfony 2+

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I am trying to extract a specific value from a html file using goutte

```
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:8081/app_dev.php');
    $htmlContent= $crawler->filter('label')->last()->html();
    var_dump($htmlContent);die();
```

in this case, I get the snippet:

```
<input type="password" maxlength="40"  myfield1="KqewkKAFyk7Vmsy" >
```

I want to extract the value of `myfield1` a. how do I achieve that?

I tried allready without any success (result is NULL):

```
    $htmlContent= $crawler->filter('label')->last()->attr('myfield1');
```

Comment: why `label` and not `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to filter by `label` instead of `input.`

This should work (assuming it's the last input):

```
$htmlContent = $crawler->filter('input')->last()->attr('myfield1');
```